# Ubuntu 14.04 and Nvidia 840M graphic card driver, prime or bumblebee ! what to choose?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia-settings

I have gone through Ubuntu forum and it suggests me to update ppa of prime or bumblebee projects. I am unsure what to choose and go ahead. users has reported many complains over prime for black screen appearance, whereas bumblebee is quite unknown.

my laptop config:
Dell 15 3542 i7
Nvidia Geforce 840M, 2gb
Intel HD controller(Haswell)
8gb DDR3L RAM ,1tb SATA HDD.

Please help me to choose best for config, if none of the choice is good, suggest alternative.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your nvidia GPU to work, you need to install "bumblebee", just like it is mentioned on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee):

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

However, your card is not supported by the default drivers, since it is too recent, and thus, you will need to take additional steps.

First of all, you must install the latest drivers `sudo apt-get install nvidia 346` (at the time of writing).

Afterwards, you must edit the file `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and replace all instances of "nvidia-current" with "nvidia-346" (It has to be replaced on **3 places** in that file).

This, however, will still make the machine boot into a black screen. The problem is that the nvidia module is being loaded before the intel one. Bumblebee creates a file `/etc/modules/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` that blacklists nvidia-modules. This file, however, hasn't been updated in a while. Therefore, you must add the following to the end of this file:

```
# 346
blacklist nvidia-346
blacklist nvidia-346-updates
blacklist nvidia-experimental-346
```

After a reboot, you should be good to go. Of course, don't forget to change "346" to the number on the driver version you have installed.